# foreach code not working for filtering API

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, api

Search by city & hotels which city and hotels have on my database. My code is not worked. Can you check my code. Maybe some mistake in the code.

```
$countryName =  $_GET['countrycode'];
$url        =  'https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/hotels/search-box?apikey=EbdwHszYlp0f7fQB6YHo40SIhu4ZAomm&south_west_corner=51.328476%2C%20-10.758522&north_east_corner=55.320949%2C%20-5.474099&check_in=2017-06-19&check_out=2017-06-29&number_of_results=1000';
$response  = file_get_contents($url);
$apiResults = json_decode($response, true);
$apiResults = $apiResults["results"];

$finalArray = [];
$dbResults   = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * 
          FROM hotels
         WHERE county = %s",
        $countryName
    ),
    ARRAY_A 
);


# If atleast 1 row is fecthed from
# database
if ($dbResults->num_rows) {
    foreach ($dbResults as $dbResult) {
        echo $storedCountryName = $dbResult["county"];
        echo $storedHotelName   = $dbResult["hotel"];
        foreach ($apiResults as $apiResult) {
            if ($storedCountryName  === $apiResult['address']['city']
                && $storedHotelName === $apiResult['property_name']) 
            {
                $finalArray[] = $apiResult;


            }

        }

    }
}
var_dump($finalArray);
```

**var_dump($finalArray); Result:**

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: what is the result of `SELECT * 
          FROM hotels
         WHERE county = %s`?

Comment: Hi @vel , its long code. can you download from here https://expirebox.com/download/41c2c494246efa0ef25d15fafef95bbb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know.

I replace this line `if ($dbResults->num_rows) {` with `if ($wpdb->num_rows>0) {`.

It should work.

```
    $countryName =  $_GET['countrycode'];
$url        =  'https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2/hotels/search-box?apikey=EbdwHszYlp0f7fQB6YHo40SIhu4ZAomm&south_west_corner=51.328476%2C%20-10.758522&north_east_corner=55.320949%2C%20-5.474099&check_in=2017-06-19&check_out=2017-06-29&number_of_results=1000';
$response  = file_get_contents($url);
$apiResults = json_decode($response, true);
$apiResults = $apiResults["results"];

$finalArray = [];

$dbResults   = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT * 
          FROM hotels
         WHERE county = %s",
        $countryName
    ),
    ARRAY_A 
);


# If atleast 1 row is fecthed from
# database
if ($wpdb->num_rows>0) {
    foreach ($dbResults as $dbResult) {
        echo $storedCountryName = $dbResult["county"];
        echo $storedHotelName   = $dbResult["hotel"];
        foreach ($apiResults as $apiResult) {
            $ResultArray= array();
            if ($storedCountryName  == $apiResult['address']['city']
                && $storedHotelName == $apiResult['property_name']) 
            {
                $ResultArray = $apiResult;
                $finalArray[] = $ResultArray;

            }

        }

    }
}
var_dump($finalArray);
```

Comment: I replace this line `if ($dbResults->num_rows) {` with `if ($wpdb->num_rows>0) {`

Comment: its worked but showing only one hotel information! In api url two hotels are match with my database

Comment: @rayan005, Answer updated. check now.

Comment: still same prob

Comment: Answer updated again. you have to check the if condition. print these value and check `$storedCountryName` && `$storedHotelName`.

Comment: sorry, still same problem. showing only "Jurys Inn Cork" hotel information

Comment: ca you share me the `$dbResults` values?

Comment: $dbResults var_dump result please download form here https://expirebox.com/download/20f245144d61a4872c259af5b718684b.html

Comment: Hi @vel. Could you see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493902/after-redirct-url-pagination-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if ($storedCountryName  == $apiResult['address']['city'] && $storedHotelName == $apiResult['property_name']) 
{
   $finalArray[] = $apiResult;

}
```

`===` means you are checking datatype as well. there might be a possibility that your database field datatype and json response string datatype doesn't match. So remove one = from condition and compare only values.

Comment: may i know why i got -1 ? I don't think my answer is incorrect.

Comment: @downvoter care to leave explanation :)