# After redirct url pagination not working

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

This is my pagination code. It's worked well after redirect page url. When I am redirecting url to another page this code not worked. This custom post pagination.

before redirect the pagination hover url was: 
http://xxxx/?industry=26&posts_per_page=12&page=3

and after redirect the pagination hover url was (and its not working): 
http://xxxx/newpage/?page=2&industry=26&location_company=0&employees=0&type=video

```
 <?php
                        echo  paginate_links( [
                            'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous', 'bizcast' ),
                            'next_text'          => __( 'Next', 'bizcast' ),
                            'before_page_number' => '',
                            'screen_reader_text' => '',
                            'total' => $videos->max_num_pages,
                            'format'       => '?page=%#%',
                            'current' => ($_GET['page'] ? $_GET['page'] : 1),
                            'type' => 'list'
                        ] );
                        ?>
```

Comment: after redirect the pagination hover url ?. i didnt get you. can you explain brief?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please see this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495765/paginate-links-not-working-after-page-redirect its same issue posted by my friend. (Same code worked in index.php but not worked in any other page)

Comment: i dont have post type video. can you some that code?. `$videos && $videos->have_posts())`

Comment: can you open chat room

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

before loop start and add 'paged' => $paged in wp query arguments.
For example:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$query_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'category_name' => 'tutorials',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged
);
```

Comment: its not works. Please see again edited I have edited my question.